Keras 3 Attention layer does not accept output from previous LSTM layers
As an exercise to get acquainted with Keras, I want to train a simple model with attention to translate sentences.
I get the following error:
A KerasTensor cannot be used as input to a TensorFlow function. A KerasTensor is a symbolic placeholder for a shape and dtype, used when constructing Keras Functional models or Keras Functions. You can only use it as input to a Keras layer or a Keras operation (from the namespaces keras.layers and keras.operations). [...]
I am not explicitly calling a tf function, only using Keras layers.
I would like to learn how to use Keras 3 (since I'm interested in support for other backends) rather than going back to Keras 2.
Any help is appreciated!
Here is the code for the model using Keras' functional API:
encoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)
decoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)

embed_size = 128
encoder_inputs_ids = text_vec_layer_en(encoder_inputs)
decoder_inputs_ids = text_vec_layer_es(decoder_inputs)
encoder_embedding_layer = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size, mask_zero=True)
decoder_embedding_layer = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size, mask_zero=True)
encoder_embeddings = encoder_embedding_layer(encoder_inputs_ids)
decoder_embeddings = decoder_embedding_layer(decoder_inputs_ids)

encoder = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(512, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, *encoder_state = encoder(encoder_embeddings)

decoder = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(512, return_sequences=True)
decoder_outputs = decoder(decoder_embeddings, initial_state=encoder_state)

# Attention layer here!
# Problems getting it to work on Keras 3
attention_layer = tf.keras.layers.Attention()
attention_outputs = attention_layer([decoder_outputs, encoder_outputs])

output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size, activation="softmax")
Y_probas = output_layer(attention_outputs)

Expected behavior: The Keras attention layer accepts Keras tensor inputs.

A suggestion by the developers on a Github issue I raised is to use a MultiHeadAttention, which does accept the outputs from the previous layers directly and is better suited for translation.
In my case, I was interested in getting acquainted with the Keras interface, so this doesn't solve the my question in spirit (Why does the Attention layer not work? Is there some logic behind this or is it a bug?) But the solution works, and you can get a working model.
